# How to access nested values in Cypress.json

Tags: cypress

Cannot access nested values in Cypress.json file.

I have just started learning Cypress and trying to organise some variables into the Cypress.json file.

The usual dot and bracket notation do not work because the key is already in single/double quotes, so I think Cypress sees it as a complete string eg. `(Cypress.env('login.username'))`.

This is my simple Cypress.json file

```
{
   "env":{
    "login":{
        "username":"Joe"
        }
   }
}
```

How can I access the name `Joe`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this, it will return the username.

```
Cypress.env('login').username // returns "Joe"
```

Read more about [Environment Variables](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Setting)

Comment: Works.  Thank you Yevhen.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon Yevhen's answer.

Nested environment variables **only** work when placed inside a separate `cypress.env.json` file in the root of your project, next to your `cypress.json` file.

This can be seen under [option #2 on the environment variables link that Yevhen already provided](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-2-cypress-env-json).

It isn't explicitly documented where this `cypress.env.json` file needs to be placed, I just wanted to share this information after having to figure it out for myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cypress.env('payment_credentials')['vendor--paypal-standard'].payerEmail
```

or just like that. even if it is only defined in your cypress.config.js as nested objects. Not a separate cypress.env.json necessary.

like:

```
payment_credentials: {
        'vendor--paypal-standard': {
            payerEmail: 'XXXX',
            payerPassword: 'XXX',
        },
        'vendor--paypal-cc': {
            cardNumber: 'XXX',
            cardDate: 'XXX',
            cardVerify: 'XXX',
            card3dSecure: 'XXX',
        },
    },
```